# Can I respond to touch directly in a sprite kit node on the scene, or do I need to go through the scene's touchesBegan method

Tags: ios, delegates, sprite-kit, delegation

Can I respond to touch directly in a SKSpriteNode on the scene, using its touchesBegan method, or do I absolutely need to go first through the scene's touchesBegan method - and then delegating it to sprite/calling the sprite's method directly? In other words, can SKSpriteNode catch the touch event, or is it just scene who does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to go through the scenes touchBegin method. What you need to do is subclass `SKSpriteNode`, and as long as `userInteractionEnabled` is set to true, you can override the touch properties inside the class to be responsive only when the sprite is touched.

Comment: This is correct, I've tested it. I wonder why this is not set to YES per default, but yeah, it isn't.

Comment: Because not all sprite nodes will have touch interaction, more often than not, you wouldn't expect your sprite to be interactive.

Comment: Kind of, yeah. Thanks a lot, fellow spritekitter!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to do this inside of the touchesBegan function.

Comment: The thing is that the sprite kit node also has this method.